# How can I make my android tablet app to look the same when it runs on phone in landscape mdoe

Tags: android

I have a android app layout for tablet. Its layout is 'landscape' based (i.e. it looks the way i want when  I run on tablet (by default landscape).

But when I run the same app on a phone, android runs in portrait mode, (it squeeze my 'landscape' layout into a portrait ).

I have tried putting 'android:screenOrientation='landscape' in my activity in my Manifest file. But that does not fix it.

Basically, what I want is when I rotate the phone by 90 % (the width is > height), I want the phone layout looks the same as what i see on tablet (which is landscape by default).

How can I do that? android:screenOrientation='landscape' does not work.

Basically, I want some thing the game 'AngryBird', it always runs in landscape mode regardless it is phone or tablet and whether the phone is rotated.

Comment: So you want your app to only run in landscape, regardless if it's a phone or tablet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use 2 flags, not just one.

First is

```
android:screenOrientation='landscape'
```

Second is

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

First will tell android to run activity in landscape mode, where as second will tell android that do not change the orientation even when user rotates the phone. Basically with 2nd flag you are overriding orientation config changes.

Comment: That's not correct for the 2nd flag. It tells the OS that you will handle configuration changes for orientation. It doesn't prevent orientation change. By default, Android destroys your activity and recreates it on orientation change. Setting this flag will prevent that behavior.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, so that is what I mean when I said "overriding orientation config changes". When you have this flag on, android will not rotate the screen. Because it assumes you are going to do that by yourself.

Comment: No, your screen still rotates. It assumes you will handle configuration for the new orientation. Your layout still flips regardless.

Comment: Yes I take that back, thanks for clearing my confusion while I was trying to answer your question. :)

Comment: By the way, weird thing. I removed screenOrientation and just left configChanges in my manifest. Also override the onConfigChanges in my activity. But for some reason, my onCreate is still getting called on rotation. I have to dig more in this. Getting more and more confused now.

Comment: That doesn't sound expected. `onConfigurationChanged` should be called and it shouldn't destroy the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done this myself, but instead of putting the main.xml layout in res/layout, try putting it in res/layout-land, so it will display this layout in landscape mode, and in res/layout-port, maybe a portrait alternative to main.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Create folder `\res\layout-land\` and place there your XML file with landscape layout. Phone choose between portrait and landscape layouts automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the `onCreate` method before you call `setContentView`:

```
setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE );
```